# Must askers be able to answer their own question?

Tags: discussion

The question is all in the title:

**Must askers be able to answer their own question?**

---

This question had been asked before, but may be easier to find than the most directly relevant previous question, [Ability to Solve Own Challenge as a Requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1352).

There are also relevant answers in [Basis for Voting to Close](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1350) and [What details should always be given for a code golf task?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/107/69850)

Comment: This is really a dupe of https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1352/194

Comment: This has turned from a simple question into an illegible mess. The edit history is available to anyone who wants to read it, and anyone who doesn't is better served by seeing a refactored question with no strike-throughs, "EDIT"s, etc.